# El Registro de un Insert de cada tabla en VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

Tengo una duda acerca de una Tabla que se necesita registrar la hora que ingreso a cada tabla Por Ejemplo: Empresa, Usuarios, Configuración del Correo y Cambio Estatus

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que utilicé para Insertar los Registros

```
'Insert de Registros

Dim vm_tabla As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim vm_sql As String = ""

Public Sub Gd_perfil()
    Dim dt As DataTable

    vm_sql = "Insert [KNTB_Bitacora] (David,getdate(),Empresa)"
    sql.Traer_info_sql(vm_sql, vm_tabla)
    GridControl1.DataSource = vm_tabla

    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Gd_perfil()

    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
End Sub
```

La pregunta es, en el botón de Insertar, debo Utlizar 4 Nombres y 4 Empresas para que quede registrado en la tabla, o cada uno?

Ejemplo:

```
vm_sql = "Insert [KNTB_Bitacora] (David,Pedro, getdate() ,Empresa, Usuarios)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la tabla de bitácora (KNTB_Bitacora) tiene 3 campos: NombreUsuario, Fecha, LugarInsercion.

Cada vez que un usuario acceda a una de esas tablas ( Empresa, Usuarios, Configuración del Correo y Cambio Estatus) quieres que la aplicación realice un INSERT.

El "Sub Gd_perfil()" debería recibir 2 parámetros y quedarse así:

`Public Sub Gd_perfil(Usuario as string, Tabla as string)`

`Dim dt As DataTable`

`vm_sql = "Insert into [KNTB_Bitacora] (NombreUsuario, Fecha, LugarInsercion) _
values ('" & Usuario & "', GetDate(), '" & Tabla & "')"`

`sql.Traer_info_sql(vm_sql, vm_tabla)`

`GridControl1.DataSource = vm_tabla`

`GridView1.BestFitColumns()`

`End Sub`

Esto se ejecutará cada vez que un usuario acceda a una de las tablas.

Comment: Por ejemplo si tengo eso `Insert KNTB_Bitacora (id,Modulo,Usuario,Fecha_Ingreso,Observaciones)` como seria en values?

Comment: Para una tabla de este tipo, el id debe ser autonumérico (identidad en SQL Server), en el caso que muestras la función deberá recibir un parámetro adicional llamado "observacion":
`Public Sub Gd_perfil(Usuario as string, Tabla as string, Observacion as string)`

Luego el insert sería:
`vm_sql = "Insert [KNTB_Bitacora] (Usuario, Fecha_Ingreso, Modulo, Observaciones) _
values ('" & Usuario & "', GetDate(), '" & Tabla & "'", '" & Observacion & "')"`

Comment: aunque me marque `NULL` en el SQL, se puede ejecutar desde Visual Studio VB?

Comment: si se ejecuta, aparece todas la tablas, pero cuando le doy click en los botones ya sea Usuarios o Empresas, no me registra los datos con las fechas actuales

Comment: Me imagino que el valor NULL debe ser de Observciones.
Para evitarlo, antes del insert pon lo siguiente

`Observacion = IIF(IsDBNull(Obsevacion), "", Observacion)`

No acabo de entender el segundo comentario. Pon un punto de interrupción en la línea `sql.Traer_info_sql(vm_sql, vm_tabla)`y mira el contenido de la variable `vm_sql`

Comment: Lo de observaciones se pone en el sql o en Visual?

Comment: porque no creo que sea la de observaciones, aparece el mensaje: `No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'id', tabla 'KNTB_Bitacora'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT.`

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido que este id no sea autonumérico. ¿Para registros anteriores, que otros valores tiene?. 
Deberías editar la tabla en SQL Server y ir a las propiedades de esta columna y ponerla como "Especificación de Identidad=Si".

Comment: los `id`, tiene valores numéricos, el `modulo` y `usuario` son valores `nvarchar`, la `fecha de ingreso` es `datetime` y en `observaciones` son valores en `text`.  Todas estan establecidas en No en las Especificaciones de Identidad, los tengo que habilitar todas o solo el `id`?

Comment: Solo en el campo Id

Comment: listo, ahora en los botones de cada tabla `Usuarios`, `Configuración del Correo`, `Empresas`, etc. En `values ('" & Usuario & "', GetDate(), '" & Tabla & "', '" & Observacion & "')` para que se activen los clicks y pueda registrarse en la Tabla, tengo que establecer en `values` los clicks que se ingresó por ejemplo en la Tabla o el botón `Empresas` para que se registre en la Tabla Bitacora?

Comment: La acción de cada botón debe ser la de llamar a `Gd_perfil`
Por ejemplo para el botón "Empresa" debería llamar 
`Gd_perfil(Usuario, "Empresa")`
Donde "Usuario" es la variable donde tienes almacenado el usuario (nombre, identificado o lo que tengas de él).

Comment: Al momento de registrarlo desde Visual Studio, aparece en blanco, para que pueda activar los clicks de un Usuario que a que horas se ingreso en cada botón en `("Usuarios, "Empresas", "Configuración del Correo", "Cambio de Estatus")`  tengo que cambiarlos a `vm_sql = "Insert [KNTB_Bitacora]` o en `Gd_perfil`?

Comment: Dentro de Gd_perfil no debes tocar nada. En modo de diseño del formulario hay un click en el botón de Empresas, allí debes seguir las instrucciones de mi anterior comentario y poner:

`Gd_perfil(Usuario, "Empresa")` 

Donde "Usuario" es la variable donde tienes almacenado el usuario (nombre, identificado o lo que tengas de él).

Comment: Encontre el Boton de Empresa `Private Sub SimpleButton7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton7.Click Frm_Configuracion.Show() End Sub` lo tengo que poner en `.Show` o dentro del `Frm`?

Comment: Lo tienes que poner antes del `End Sub`

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, al ultimo en `"Empresa"` tengo que poner `as string`?

Comment: Al momento de poner el `Gd_perfil` dice que el `Usuario` o `Empresas`, no está declarado estoy en `Frm_MdiConfig` esa es para el `SimpleButton7`, en `Frm_Configuración` tengo que agregar la `public sub Gd_perfil(Usuario, "Empresa")`? porque el `Frm_Bitacora` es para la tabla de Bitacora

Comment: Gd_perfil(Usuario, "Empresa"). Dónde Usuario debe se la variable de la aplicación donde tienes almacenado el identificador del usuario (email, nombre, o lo que quieras ingresar en la base de datos)

Comment: Ya lo puse, pero me dice que tiene `Demasiados Argumentos para Public Sub` le genero el código auxiliar?